# ReactJS: How to submit the form values as JSON object without using redux-form.

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

I am using `redux-form` to submit form values as JSON object to POST service. But `redux-form` fields(`<Field />`) doesn't support events like `onChange` , `onBlur`. So I want to use the default components like `<select><option></select>`, `<input type="text" />`, but if I use the plain html components, events like onChange will work. But here I am unable to submit the form values as object to service without `redux-form`. Please guide...

Thanks,
Shash

Answer (score 0):

redux-form does support it with custom components passed to `<Field />`.

One of the way is this (taken from the docs)

> 1. A component
>
> This can be any component class that you have written or have imported
>   from a third party library.
>
> // MyCustomInput.js
>
> ```
> import React, { Component } from 'react'
>
> class MyCustomInput extends Component {
>   render() {
>     const { value, onChange } = this.props
>     return (
>       <div>
>         <span>The current value is {value}.</span>
>         <button type="button" onClick={() => onChange(value + 1)}>Inc</button>
>         <button type="button" onClick={() => onChange(value - 1)}>Dec</button>
>       </div>
>     )
>   }
> }
> Then, somewhere in your form...    
> import MyCustomInput from './MyCustomInput'
>
> <Field component={MyCustomInput}/>
> ```

It would be much easier for you to just make redux-form submit your values, since you're already using it.

[Docs on Field](http://redux-form.com/6.0.0-alpha.4/docs/api/Field.md/)

Comment: It doesn't even have to be a custom component, you can still use onChange with just plain "select" as a component. 

The docs you're referring to are for 6.0.0 alpha 4 though, here's the most recent version: http://redux-form.com/6.6.1/docs/api/Field.md/

You can see that you can pass an onChange-prop to Field as well.

Comment: But is it possible to pass the onChange like this ? `<Field component={MyCustomInput} onChange={handleChange} />` here `handleChange` function contains some increment and decrement functionality.

Comment: I'm not sure if that will work because redux-form supplies an `onChange` prop to the field rendering function. You can alway supply the handler function using a different prop name like `customOnChange`. Then call both `onChange` (provided by redux-form, and needed in order to propagate the event) and `customOnChange` (to do whatever your custom logic is). However, I wonder what the connection between submitting form values as JSON is to `onChange`. The form values are already provided to your submit handler as a Javascript object.